# Is there a way to perform compile time type-check in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, compile-time, typechecking

I know Ruby is dynamically and strongly typed, but AFAIK, current syntax doesn't allow checking the type of arguments at compile time due to lack of explicit type notation (or contract) for each argument.

If I want to perform compile-time type check, what (practically matured) options do I have?

**Update**

What I mean *type-check* is something like typical statically typed language. Such as C.
For example, C function denotes type of each argument and compiler checks passing-in argument is correct or not.

```
void func1(struct AAA aaa)
{
    struct BBB bbb;
    func1(bbb);  // Wrong type. Compile time error.
}
```

As an another example, Objective-C does that by putting explicit type information.

```
- (id)method1:(AAA*)aaa
{
    BBB* bbb = [[AAA alloc] init];  // Though we actually use correctly typed object...
    [self method1:bbb];             // Compile time warning or error due to type contract mismatch.
}
```

I want something like that.

**Update 2**

Also, I mean *compile-time = before running the script*. I don't have better word to describe it…

Comment: example please... what do you want to check?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I updated the question to add an example.

Comment: Do you have the compiler?

Comment: @Agis I updated again. I intended compile-time = before running the script.

Comment: @Eonil So you want static types in Ruby?

Comment: @Agis I added another example of Objective-C case. Which is dynamically typed, but compile-time type-checked.

Comment: Simple answer: No.  And you're doing it wrong.  You are completely missing the point of duck typing.

Comment: None that I know of, but contracts.ruby (github.com/egonschiele/contracts.ruby) will give you dynamic type checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a project for developing a type system, a type inferencer, a type checker and a syntax for type annotations for (a subset of) Ruby, called [Diamondback Ruby](http://www.cs.umd.edu/projects/PL/druby/). It was abandoned 4 years ago, you can find [its source on GitHub](https://github.com/mfurr/Diamondback-Ruby/).

But, basically, that language would no longer be Ruby. If static types are so important to you, you should probably just use a statically typed language such as Haskell, Scala, ML, Agda, Coq, ATS etc. That's what they're here for, after all.

Comment: Diamondback Ruby has now turned into a library called RDL if you want to check it out https://github.com/plum-umd/rdl

Answer (score 2):

[RDL](https://github.com/plum-umd/rdl) is a library for static type checking of Ruby/Rails programs. It has type annotations included for the standard library and (I think) for Rails. It lets you add types to methods/variables/etc. like so:

file.rb:

```
require 'rdl'

type '(Fixnum) -> Fixnum', typecheck: :now
def id(x)
  "forty-two"
end
```

And then running file.rb will perform static type checking:

```
$ ruby file.rb
.../lib/rdl/typecheck.rb:32:in `error':  (RDL::Typecheck::StaticTypeError)
.../file.rb:5:5: error: got type `String' where return type `Fixnum' expected
.../file.rb:5:     "forty-two"
.../file.rb:5:     ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

It seems to be pretty well documented!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want static types. There is not an effective way to do this in Ruby due to the language's dynamic nature.

A naive approach I can think of is to make a "contract" like this:

```
def up(name)
  # name(string)

  name.upcase
end
```

So the first line of each method will be a comment declaring what type each argument must have.

Then implement a tool that will statically scan & analyze the source and catch such errors by scanning the call sites of the above method and check the type of the passed argument *whenever possible*.

For example this would be easy to check:

```
x = "George"
up(x)
```

but how would you check this one:

```
x = rand(2).zero? "George" : 5
up(x)
```

In other words, most of the time the types are impossible to be deduced before runtime.

However if you do not care about the *"type checking"* happening statically, you could also do:

```
def up(name)
  raise "TypeError etc." unless name.is_a? String
  # ...
end
```

In any way, I don't think you will benefit from the above. I would recommend to make use of duck typing instead.

Comment: The type of your second example can be modeled as the *union type* `String | Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't check this in a static time-sense, you can use conditionals in your methods to run only after checking the object.
Here the `#is_a?` and `#kind_of?` come in handy...

```
def method(variable)
    if variable.is_a? String
        ...
    else
        ...
    end
end
```

You would have the choice of returning specified error values or raise an exception. Hopefully this is close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a "compile-time" type check, but in Ruby, there is no "compile" phase. Static analysis of Ruby code is almost impossible, since any method, even from the built-in classes, can be redefined at runtime. Classes can also be dynamically created and instantiated at runtime. How would you do type-checking for a class which doesn't even exist when the program starts?

Surely, your real goal is not just to "type-check your code". Your goal is to "write code that works", right? Type-checking is just a tool which can help you "write code that works". However, while type-checking is helpful, it has its limits. It can catch some simple bugs, but not most bugs, and not the most difficult bugs.

When you choose to use Ruby, you are giving up the benefits of type-checking. However, Ruby *may* allow you to get things done with much *less* code than other languages you are used to. Writing programs using *less* code, means that generally there are less bugs for you to fix. If you use Ruby skillfully, I believe the tradeoff is worth it.

Although you can't type-check your code in Ruby, there is great value in using assertions which check method arguments. In some cases, those assertions might check the type of an argument. More frequently, they will check other properties of the arguments. Then you need some tests which exercise the code. You will find that with a relatively small number of tests, you will catch more bugs than your C/C++ compiler can do.

Comment: My goal isn't just writing code that works. My goal is getting thing done correctly, easily, and rapidly as much as possible. In my experience, it always require more code to satisfy the three conditions without type-check because I have to manually write all the checks what type-check does automatically. And that's because I'm super-error-prone person so without automated checking tool, it takes too long to write correct code for me.

Comment: Depending on how you use it, Ruby may help you "get things done correctly", more easily and rapidly than other languages you have used. But you can't blindly apply each and every technique which you already know. Ruby is very different from the other languages you have learned (at least the ones listed in your profile), and to use it effectively, you will have to change your way of thinking a bit. Some things may not make sense at first, but as you get a deeper understanding of this new language, they will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the idea of a "Pluggable type system". It means adding a static type system to a dynamic language, but the programmer decides what should be typed and what is left untyped. The typechecker stands aside the core language and it is usually implemented as a library. It can either do static checking or check types at runtime in a special "checked" mode that should be used during development and to execute tests.

The type checker for Ruby I found is called Rtc (Ruby Type Checker). [Github](https://github.com/plum-umd/rtc), [academic paper](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jfoster/papers/oops13.pdf). The motivation is to make the requirements on a type of a parameter of a function or method explicit, move the requirements out of the tests into type annotations and turn the type annotation into an "executable documentation". [Source](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2014/05/06/gradual-type-checking-for-ruby/).